# преобразовать строку во время/секунды с помощью команды strptime

Tags: c++, python, строки, datetime, gnuplot

Подскажите, можно ли получить секунды/время из строки с помощью команды strptime с произвольным форматом времени

Например, интересуют случаи, когда корректно бы распознавались такие форматы

```
str = "1m";
str = "2h5m10s";
str = "3m18s";
str = "57s";
str = "2h9s";
```

`strptime("%Hh%Mm%Ss", string)` выдает некорректный результат, кроме случая `1h2m3s`

Comment: Можно, только строку с форматом времени надо будет использовать соответствующую.

Comment: Ну набросайте свой анализатор; для такого строгого формата - раз плюнуть... Или проверяйте наличие `h`, `m`, `s` и в зависимости от этого подставляйте нужную строку формата...

Comment: @Harry, просто думал, что можно в 1 строчку/1 команду решить проблему :(

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `strptime` не получится.
Я бы предложил сделать так (python):

```
import re

def cnv(astr):
    tdict={"h":"00", "m":"00", "s":"00"}
    res = ""
    for elem in re.findall(r'(\d*)(\D)', astr):
        tdict[elem[1]] = elem[0].zfill(2)
    res=":".join([x for x in tdict.values()])
    return res
```

Проверяем:

```
print(cnv("1m"))
print(cnv("2h5m10s"))
print(cnv("3m18s"))
print(cnv("57s"))
print(cnv("2h9s"))
```

Получаем:

```
00:01:00
02:05:10
00:03:18
00:00:57
02:00:09
```